# div doesn't expand to fit content

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a top menu and the div containing the menu items doesn't seem to be stretching to fit them. I'm quite bad at CSS and rarely use it, so I apologize if it's a simple answer. Any help would be appreciated!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uax30g8s/9/

```
<div className={`${styles.topMenuDesktop}`}>
    <div className={`${styles.desktopLogo}`}>
        Logo
    </div>
    <div className={`${styles.topMenuItems}`}>
        <div className={styles.topMenuItem}>Support</div>
        <div className={styles.topMenuItem}>Pricing</div>
        <div className={styles.topMenuItem}>Blog</div>
    </div>
    <div className={`${styles.topMenuAccount}`}>
        <button className={styles.login}>Login</button>
        <button className={styles.signupTop}>Signup</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.topMenuDesktop {
    display: flex;
}

.desktopLogo {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.topMenuItems {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 8%;
}

.topMenuItem {
    margin-right: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code with a few aesthetic changes.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}


.topMenu {
  width: 100%;margin:10px 0;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menuItems {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 8%;width:100%;
}

.menuItem{
  margin-right: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.auth {
  display:flex;
}

.auth button {
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topMenu">
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="menuItems">
    <div class="menuItem">Item</div>
    <div class="menuItem">Item</div>
    <div class="menuItem">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="auth">
    <button>Login</button>
    <button>Signup</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So by adding `width:100%` to `.topMenu` it stretches the topMenu div full screen (and it's responsive because % is a relative unit). Also, I have added a top and bottom margin of `10px` to `.topMenu` to give it some space from the top of screen. Finally, adding `display:flex` to `.auth` makes the two buttons go horizontally instead of one on top of each other. Also added an horizontal margin to the buttons. Does that work for you?

Comment: glad i could help